# Push to a new array inside a map/promise

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is a simplified version of my current setup.

When running this code you'll notice that modifying the `changes` array also manipulates the original `referrals` array. Is this because I'm `push`ing to the `changes` array inside a map function? How can I modify the `changes` array without modifying the `referrals` array?

```js
var referrals = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
    change: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Sally',
    change: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Kim',
    change: true
  }
];

var changes = [];

var process = referrals.map(function(referral) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (referral.change) {
      changes.push(referral);
    }
    resolve();
  });
});

Promise.all(process).then(function() {
  console.log('referrals before:', referrals);
  changes = changes.map(function(change) {
    change.change_id = change.id;
    delete change.id;
    return change;
  });

  console.log('changes:', changes);
  console.log('referrals after:', referrals);
});
```

Comment: You're not changing the `referrals` Array. You're changing the Objects it contains. And you'll have the same results without using Promises. When you push your Objects into the `changes` Array, you're actually pushing references to the Objects that are in the `referrals` Array. Not copies of them, which is what you seem to think. So then, when you change a property of these Objects, these differences will show everywhere these Objects are referenced. To solve this, look up "JS clone Object"

Comment: WTH are you using promises at all? There's nothing asynchronous in your code.

Comment: @Bergi I need a promise in my actual code because I'm going some requests between each object. I slimmed down my posted example.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to create a deep copy of the inner objects, you can do it with lodash deepClone, or spread operator.

Something like that:

```
var referrals = [
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'John',
  change: true
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'Sally',
  change: false
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: 'Kim',
  change: true
}
];

var changes = [];

var process = referrals.map(function(referral) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (referral.change) {
      changes.push({...referral}); // You will create a copy here.
    }
    resolve();
  });
});

Promise.all(process).then(function() {
  console.log('referrals before:', referrals);
  changes = changes.map(function(change) {
  change.change_id = change.id;
  delete change.id;
  return change;
});

console.log('changes:', changes);
console.log('referrals after:', referrals);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks blex for walking me through what was going on here. Essentially when I was pushing the object to a new array, I was pushing the entire reference and not just a copy. Using `Object.assign` to clone the object solves my issue.

Here is the entire edit for reference:

```js
var referrals = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
    change: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Sally',
    change: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Kim',
    change: true
  }
];

var changes = [];

var process = referrals.map(function(referral) {
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (referral.change) {
      changes.push(Object.assign({}, referral));
    }
    resolve();
  });
});

Promise.all(process).then(function() {
  console.log('referrals before:', referrals);
  changes = changes.map(function(change) {
    change.change_id = change.id;
    delete change.id;
    return change;
  });

  console.log('changes:', changes);
  console.log('referrals after:', referrals);
});
```