# Modifying Array inside a map/promise (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference, promise

In the code provided below, I would like to modify the 'image' field of each object (article) stored in the 'articles' array. I know that I can create an empty array and push a deep copy of each article one by one using the spread operator as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45721828/push-to-a-new-array-inside-a-map-promise). Is there any way I can change the contents of the array 'in place'? I have tried passing articles as a third argument, and I'm still not able to modify the 'image' field of each article stored in the array. Thanks in advance.

```
let requests = articles.map((article, i)=>{
     return new Promise((resolve) => {
          articleImage.findById(article.image, (err, theImage)=>{
               if(err) return res.status(400).send(err);
               articles[i].image = theImage.source;
               resolve();
          });
     });
});
Promise.all(requests).then(res.status(200).send(articles));
```

Comment: First of all map is sync and promise is async! They cannot be coupled together. Your data is processed after promise is resolved. So you cannot do async operations in synchronous loops i.e. for, forEach, map, etc

Comment: @MeetZaveri `map` is totally fine to map an array of values to an array of promises. There's nothing wrong with the usage of `map` and `Promise.all` in the above snippet

Comment: Your problem is that `then()` takes a callback *function*, but you call `res.status(200).send(articles)` immediately (and pass its result, `undefined`, to `then`). Wrap it in a function expression.

Comment: @Bergi I decided to modify each article in the array, then resolve each promise with each modified article, and then wrap the response in a function, as you suggested, with 'requests' as argument. It's not technically modifying the articles in place, but at the very least I'm not manually creating an array and pushing stuff to it. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @MeetZaveri I don't see why using a map to synchronously create an array of Promises that will then resolve/reject as part of the array at a later time could cause any inconsistencies. Could you share some instances where mapping promises into an array could cause inconsistencies? In this situation, it wasn't that causing the problem.